# How to create combobox when selected item it adds this anywhere?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

[image]

How to this for combobox?I have long stackpanel which first it has only combobox.And when i select anything from combobox it will be added as button or other thing like on the picture.And it can be closed

[EDIT] I need anything on WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job nicely in WPF; http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MultiComboBox.aspx

[image: MultiComboBox]

> The combo box that ships with WPF does not support selecting multiple
>   items...
>   This article describes a WPF combo box that supports both. It also
>   describes a list box, which the combo box inherits from, that supports
>   binding to the SelectedItems

Alternatively: [WPF: ComboBox with CheckBoxes as items (it will even update on the fly!)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justguy/archive/2009/01/19/wpf-combobox-with-checkboxes-as-items-it-will-even-update-on-the-fly.aspx)

Recently I’ve come across something weird… I needed a ComboBox that will allow the user to select multiple items. 
The the solution coming to mind is using CheckBoxes. I have found several examples, but neither one displayed the selected items with pretty commas like this;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure what you are asking for but you can use this.

[jquery tokenizing](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/)

Comment: it's about WPF, and not any web technology

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

**jQuery Chosen Plugin**

http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/jquery-chosen.php